# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-firebase(from versions: )

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi

I want to install python-firebase on the Raspberry Pi.
So I found this page (https://pypi.org/project/python-firebase/) and followed the manual.

and I used the comment below :

```
$ sudo pip install requests==1.1.0
$ sudo pip install python-firebase
```

When I wrote the second comment, I got the error below

```
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-firebsae(from versions: ) No matching distribution found for python-firebase
```

How can I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the project's [github](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase) site the installation differs a bit.

Try this (if you're on Python3+):

```
pip3 install requests
pip3 install python-firebase
```

Comment: My python version on the Raspberry pi  is 3.7.0. I did what you advised, but I get the error. 
Error is Could not install packages due to an EnvironmenetError : 403 Client Error : Forbidden for url : https://www.piwheels.org/simple/python-firebase/